# How can I disable syntax autocomplete of JSX properties?

Tags: intellij-idea, reactjs, jsx

I have an issue where IntelliJ (ultimate) auto inserts double quotes in JSX. Take the following example. Starting with a `div`,

```
<div className />
```

once I type `=`, IntelliJ updates the div to the following:

```
<div className="" />
```

Now, that would have been nice if I was about to supply a string and I wanted to use double quotes, but I always prefer single quotes and I mostly need to reference variables like `this.props`. Is there a way to tell IntelliJ to stop autocompleting JSX syntax? I would like to disable just this feature and keep the other features, like auto-updating tag names while I edit one end of the tag, but this is annoying enough that I would accept disabling it all.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I'm using IntelliJ IDEA 2016.1.2.  In this version, you can disable this behavior in

```
Editor -> General -> Smart Keys
```

under `Settings`.  Uncheck the box for `Add quotes for attribute value...`.

Comment: That's it! Man, IntelliJ needs to aggregate all these language specific options together. I wouldn't think JSX should inherit all of the html settings either, considering it isn't valid HTML.

Comment: (IntelliJ 2018.2) It's worth noting that disabling this also disables IntelliJ auto-adding `{}` too, as in `propName={}`